# PHP MySQL compare two columns and return by order?

Tags: php, mysql

Simple question wheres mistake?

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM orders 
    WHERE Username='$username' 
        AND completed > ordered 
    ORDER BY completed ASC 
    LIMIT 1
") or die(mysql_error());
```

No errors and no data.

Comment: SQL is in the correct syntax; can you verify that the specified `$username` has orders?

Comment: I can't see any syntax errors. Your `$username` variable might be empty. Try to [`print()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) it to check.

Comment: Did you try the sql directly in phpMyAdmin to see if the query get results. The syntax is correct.

Comment: usernme is not empty and data is in orders as well will test from phpAdmin right away

Comment: From phpAdmin i get "MySQL returned an empty result set"

Comment: If that's the case, then there are no records where Username = '$username' AND completed > ordered. There's nothing technically wrong with your query unless your logic is incorrect.

Comment: Right matt discovered myself as well already. Thanks anyway

Comment: The mistake is using `mysql_query`. **DO NOT DO THIS**. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for your query may be correct, but your algorithm probably isn't:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE Username = ? 
AND completed > ordered 
ORDER BY completed ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

(And then make sure you bind your query against `$username` to mitigate SQL injection attacks.)

You have an `orders` table which presumably contains...what does it contain? It can't be a datestamp because *all* orders will be completed after they were made.

So it must be an INT? And you want to select those who have *more orders fulfilled than were made* (`AND completed > ordered`) which is hopefully impossible at your company. Try `completed < ordered`.

Comment: You are right that was my mistake. Need to take a break :)

Comment: This should be `WHERE Username=?` because putting arbitrary user data in SQL is **NOT** a good idea.

Comment: @tadman I assume the downvote was you. If you look closely, you'll see that my code is not a suggested correction, but a reformat of the OP's original code, simply cut up for clarity (it's the bare SQL statement, and not even a PHP fragment). You're right, but there is a lot to fix in there beyond that; I only responded within the scope of the OPs question.

Comment: @NikolaK, I didn't know you could force language highlighting on SO! Thanks for that!

Comment: @msanford You're welcome :) [Read more about syntax highlight on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)

Comment: @NikolaK. And that was the reference material I was just looking for.

Comment: Responding within the specific scope of the question is not always good enough. A proper answer would at least outline the hazards. A better answer would show how to avoid them.

Comment: @tadman You make a good point; better now?

Comment: Looking good. It's not just injection attacks you need to worry about, unless you consider, for example, simply being Irish to be an attack. All too many people with names like O'Malley have discovered why proper SQL escaping is important.

Comment: @tadman Indeed, as a French-speaking user and developer, I've similarly had to deal with the « l' ». I will try not to fall into the trap of a concept being so much integrated into my way of doing things that I overlook it...

Answer (score -1):

Ok sorry to bother everyone but it was simple typo notice ">" it should be "<" cause completed cant be bigger than ordered that's it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE Username='$username' AND completed > ordered ORDER BY completed ASC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Inserting arbitrary strings into a SQL statement is not cool. I'm downvoting any and all examples that make use of the hazardously bad `mysql_query`.

Comment: Please don't give examples with `mysql_query`. It's too dangerous to be used.

Comment: username is escaped and im updating script from mysql to mysqli so without knowing background of script or reasons downvoting is not cool

Comment: If it's not *obvious* that it's escaped, you can't *assume* it's escaped. If you're using `mysql_query` in a new application you're doing it wrong. Period.